# Selenium driver.get gives different page source than actual source in browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
url="https://www.clinicalkey.com/ui/service/search?ckproduct=CK_US&fields=cid,itemtitle,eid,contenttype,hubeid,refimage,pdfeid,sourcetitle,pagerange,coverdatestart,authorlist,volumeissue,authorg,condition,intervention,copyrightyear,issn,pubdate,datecreatedtxt,daterevisedtxt,statustype,exactsourcetitle,label,sectionid,sourcecopyright,sourceeditor,sourcetype,toc,volume,issue,pagefirst,pagelast,pageinfo,chaptertitle,chapternumber,ngcsynthesisurl,altlangeid,provider,summary,ref,reftitle,altlang,lang,srcid,tradenames,subtype,sections,sectiontitle,chptitle,doctype,embargo,sectionids&fullTextOnly=true&group=true&nestMedlineData=true&nestStudyTypes=true&onlyEntitled=true&query=tumor,+kidney&rows=1&sections=results,facets,resultsanalysis,bestbets,topicpages,didyoumean,didyoumean,disambiguations&showExpandedResult=true&showSelectedContent=false&start=0"


res = driver.get(url)

print(driver.page_source)
```

The output of code:-

```
<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"start":0,"numberfound":818,"results":[{"cid":"298362","itemtitle":"Renal Tumors Classification, Biology, and Banking Study"...</pre></body></html>
```

The output shown in browser on calling the same url is:-

```
 <html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"start":0,"numberfound":15788,"results":[{"cid":"319980","itemtitle":"Acquired Cystic Kidney Disease and Malignant Neoplasms: Cancer in Dialysis Patients".......</pre></body></html>
```

Comment: Neither I've got. Only this one: <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"response":{"message":"No Active Session.","status":902}}</pre>

Comment: Same here.  Are you sure you have the correct URL?